# How do I transfer an array of values in C++ into a 2 dimensional Matrix in Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab

So right now I'm trying to create a 3-D surface plot of pixel intensities of a depth image using MatLab and C++.

I already have the values of each pixel saved into an array called `base` which has the size of the entire image dimension:

```
int base[DIMENSION];
```

I then used `mxCreateDoubleMatrix` to create my `mxArray` pointer for matlab and attempted to transfer the contents of the base array into the later mentioned `mxArray` using the `memcpy` function:

```
mxArray* Floor = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(VERTICAL, HORIZONTAL, mxREAL);
memcpy((void *)mxGetPr(Floor), (void *)base, sizeof(int)*(370*386));
engPutVariable(m_pEngine, "Floor", Floor); 
engEvalString(m_pEngine, "surf(Floor)");
```

With this method I simply get a blank 3-D plot.

Another method that I had tried was trying to use the `mxCreateNumericMatrix` function.

```
mxArray* Floor = mxCreateNumericMatrix(VERTICAL, HORIZONTAL,      mxINT8_CLASS,mxREAL);
memcpy((void *)mxGetPr(Floor), (void *)base, sizeof(int)*(370*386));
engPutVariable(m_pEngine, "Floor", Floor); 
engEvalString(m_pEngine, "surf(Floor)");
system("pause");
```

But using the later method I get a runtime exception.

Comment: you are creating a double matrix and filling it with ints....... you can not do that its a **double** matrix

Comment: Images rarely have one dimension.  Clarify what you mean.

Comment: @Yakk they do in memory

Comment: There is a documentation example related: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/matlab/680/introduction-to-mex-api/14732/pass-a-3d-matrix-from-matlab-to-c#t=20170303143848000181